# Using Tsql Escape Character in C# Entity Framework Linq

Tags: c#, .net, regex, linq, entity-framework

I'm using C# 4.5.1 and Entity Framework 6 - Ms Sql Server 2012

I'm storing node id's of tree like; "[23][51]" in one coloumn.

Therefore; You can query them like this;

```
SELECT TOP 1000 NodeIds
FROM [RingTest].[dbo].[Calls] 
WHERE NodeIds LIKE '%![53!]%' ESCAPE '!'
```

But I can't do this linq. My C# linq code is here;

```
if (input.TreeNodeId.HasValue)
{
      string treeNodeIdwithParentheses = string.Format("[{0}]", input.TreeNodeId);
      query = query.Where(x => x.NodeIds.Contains(treeNodeIdwithParentheses));
}
```

This linq generating result as: Select every "NodeIds" that include 5 or 3.

So as you can see, "[]" are special characters. >[Msdn Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)<

But I need to use it in my C# linq. How can do that ?

Perheps with using a "regex way", not "contains" ?

Comment: The code you have posted should work just fine (although I would recommend changing your variable name, as `[` and `]` are square brackets, not parentheses). Are you receiving a runtime error or simply not returning any results from `query`? It would be helpful if you posted the remaining code that configures `query`, as if it isn't returning results, it may be another portion of the query that is to blame.

Comment: Do you encounter any specific problem ? AFAIK the opening bracket will automatically be escaped with a `~` (EF6.1) and your code should work as it is, generating something like `SELECT TOP 1000 NodeIds
FROM [RingTest].[dbo].[Calls] 
WHERE NodeIds LIKE '%~[53]%' ESCAPE '~'`

Comment: Ok, after updating EF and refactoring code a little bit. I saw ESCAPE keyword in sql profiler. So you can delete my question if you want. Sorry folks. And thanks for two answers...